# named pipe terminating session

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

I'm writing a short program that's polling the buffer of a named pipe. To test it out, I'll log into 'nobody' and echo into the pipe. while it's hanging, I log in from a different user and run the program that reads the buffer. When it runs, the program returns nothing and the other user is logged out of the system. Here's the read function:

```
void ReadOut( char * buf )
{
    ZERO_MEM( buffer, BUF_SIZE );

    int pipe = open( buf, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK );

    if( pipe < 0 )
    {
            printf( "Error %d has occured.\n" , pipe );
            return;
    }

    while( read( pipe, buffer, 2 ) > 0 ) printf( "%s \n" , buffer );
    close( pipe );

    return;
}
```

Comment: the 'write' function, similar to this, works just fine. This function also works when I take out O_NONBLOCK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This function also works when I take out O_NONBLOCK

When you mark a file descriptor as non blocking, all the operations that normally can block (for example `read(2)`, and `write(2)`) return `-1` instead and set `errno = EAGAIN`.

So in your case `read` immediately returns -1 signaling "*I'm not ready right now, try again later*".

Comment: I know. The problem is that there's not an indication of error and I'm getting no data.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Did you check the `errno` filled by `read` when it returned < 0 ?

Comment: what do you mean? i'm new to linux

Comment: @TaylorFlores Well then how can you state "there's not an indication of error" ?

Comment: the while loop should repeat if there's any number return less than zero, so that's telling me that there isn't any error being returned.

Comment: *the while loop should repeat if there's any number return less than zero* Look again at your code.

Comment: okay that worked, thanks! The first error as -1, so I changed it to poll the buffer three times and that's when I started getting data.